# How to move a file between deb packages?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, apt, deb

For example, imagine we have two packages: `banana.deb` and `banana-common.deb`. Inside `banana.deb`, we have some file `banana.data`, that is quite big and changes rarely. Both packages are currently at version `0.0.1`, and `banana` depends on `banana-common`.

Now, because we want to reduce `banana.deb` size, we want to move that `banana.data` file into `banana-common` package. If I just do that (updating both versions to `0.0.2` and try to install with `dpkg -i`, I see the following:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i banana-common.deb banana.deb
...
dpkg: error processing banana-common.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/local/banana/banana.data', which is also in package banana 0.0.1
```

How can I fix it without removing the package first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `debian/control` add something like

```
Conflicts: banana (<= 0.0.2)
```

to the package section for `banana-common`.

Comment: And that would force dpkg to install them in parallel?

Comment: Man pages say something like "The package maintenance software  will not allow conflicting packages to be installed at the same time". Wouldn't it just fail the installation?

Comment: It makes `banana-common` 0.0.2 to conflict with `banana` 0.0.1 but not `banana` 0.0.2. That makes the package manager first upgrades `banana` before it upgrades `banana-common`

Comment: But new `banana` will be dependent on `0.0.2` version of `banana-common`, so it can't be upgraded, either.

Comment: `sudo dpkg -i banana-common.deb banana.deb` or `apt-get upgrade` will upgrade both in right order.